# Is it possible to get an animated .gif as a folder icon?

Tags: icons

I was wondering if it was possible to use animated .gif as icons for folders/files. I already know how to add pictures using the getinfo and pasting but I couldn't figure out if their was a way to make an animated one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which operating systems this is for.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Can you please tel us what OS you are using? Without this information it is hard to answer.

Comment: Sorry, OSX version 10.9.3

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not possible, see [discussions.apple.com/thread/964383](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/964383)

Macs use ICNS format for the icons, not GIF so it's just converting the top image in your GIF to ICNS. ICNS allows for multiple image states but I believe that it takes specific coding in the application itself to animate items for doc notifications or whatever (adium messenger for instance has their duck icon flap it's arms when you receive a new IM). Mac OS itself can display multiple states for open or closed folders.

Source [Yahoo answers; User:rehpotsirhc](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120705152157AAeCGxw)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible
**1. First you need to convert your (hopefully) pre downloaded gif into an animated png. EZgif will do.**
**2. Second convert file and save as .apng. Press space on your file and press command c. paste on folder for animated icon. Boom**

(In ezgif.com the toolbar at the top, far right apng. Upload your image. Right click output> save image as. Should be .png now you are good to go)